# Из какой библиотеки функция wglChoosePixelFormatARB?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

не могу понять из какую библиотеку не подключил что на функцию

`wglChoosePixelFormatARB (hdc, attribList, NULL, 1, & PixelFormat, & NumFormats);`

пишет

> 'wglChoosePixelFormatARB' was not declared in this scope

пишу винапи приложение с опенгл, пытаюсь создать опенгл контекст в окне

Comment: Может поможет https://gist.github.com/nickrolfe/1127313ed1dbf80254b614a721b3ee9c

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо самостоятельно извлекать функции из динамической библиотеки используемого вами провайдера посредством LoadLibraryW + GetProcAddress .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library, то есть glew.

Comment: скорее всего это правильный ответ, но glew у меня к dev c++ не подключено поєтому перейду на vs

Comment: @AlbionMuz Это неправильный ответ, glew - это только загрузчик.